# Xcode has a problem linking glib as static library

Tags: c++, xcode, glib

I'm trying to implement glib in my c++ code as a static library, and so have linked the libglib-2.0.a file provided when installing glib through brew in the "Link Binary with libraries" build phase.

xcode then erroneously links the dynamic libglib-2.0.dylib to my project instead. I can delete the .a library that I linked and the project still compiles and works just fine , but touching the never included dylib either at runtime or at compilation messes up the execution.

What do

I tried removing the dylib, reinstalling the .a, compiling the .a library as a source instead, without any success

Comment: What build settings did you change to tell Xcode to link that library statically?  Posting a screenshot would probably communicate best (for once).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I clearly refer to the static library in xcode, but the program tries to load the dynamic library during execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73849334/why-do-i-clearly-refer-to-the-static-library-in-xcode-but-the-program-tries-to)